# What is the current simplest way to use ES6 / Import statements etc in Node v 10

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm fairly new to nodejs. With the evolution of nodejs ( I have just installed v.10 ) what is the current simplest way to use ES6 features ( import statements etc )  in a new nodejs project - that "just works" . I want the least dependencies and the method with the fastest path to "just works".

I am finding the posts on the web a bit confusing.

- Babel was installed previously for this sort of thing I understand
- Node 10 Says ( [Here](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) ) enable using node --experimental-modules my-app.mjs
- [This post](https://medium.com/web-on-the-edge/tomorrows-es-modules-today-c53d29ac448c) seems quite authoritative , but I think it's about creating packages more than using the syntax.

Please help! I seem to get the following errors for;

```
import {MagentoAccountApi} from 'js-magento-client';
```

Error 1:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at new Script (vm.js:74:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:246:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:298:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:646:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:589:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:528:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:719:10)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:228:19)
```

If I try renaming the file to have an extension .mjs and load using: node --experimental-modules .\mtest.mjs , then I get this error:

```
(node:20224) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
file:///F:/node/magento-test/mtest.mjs:1
import {MagentoAccountApi} from 'js-magento-client';
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: The requested module 'js-magento-client' does not provide an export named 'MagentoAccountApi'
    at ModuleJob._instantiate (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:89:21)
```

I don't know if that is a packagage error , or a setup error.

Maybe Babel is still the right / easiest way to make this work..?  I guess I don't want to start using something the is going to be deprecated soon.

Comment: Since you're just starting out, do you actually want to be using experimental features? You can use normal node CommonJS module syntax (`require` and `exports`) and avoid all of the experimental stuff (`import` and `export`), which would almost certainly make starting out easier.

Comment: Thanks  @loganfsmyth , yes I do want to use the latest features. I find async / await a lot more intuitive and manageable than the .then structures , and many other things.

Comment: ES module syntax is one very specific feature that is still very experimental. You can still use any number of other features, so the question is, what is your goal by using the new experimental module syntax. I'd say "the current simplest way" would be to use any new feature than works, but ignoring ES module syntax for now. It's still experimental because it's still in flux and may change.

Comment: Why es6 import/export has not been supported yet by Node.js is because it is still incomplete. IMO, es6 import/export conflicts with some of NPM features like `optionalDependencies` (Not sure whether it should be a concern or not). Since `require` is actually a function call, you can **conditionally** require a module to make optional dependencies not crash the process if it's not present; however, es6 import will break this since it cannot be conditional import.

Comment: 'Latest' doesn't mean 'better'. It's not a good idea to do that, especially if you're new to Node. Experimental features aren't production-ready. You may have problems providing experimental flags to node executable in some environments. Any way, js-magento-client isn't ES module and cannot be imported, end of the story.

Comment: @momocow This is what dynamic imports are for. Which aren't drop-in replacements for require because they are async.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present, with the experimental loader, CommonJS interoperability only allows for a *single default export*. You can't use named exports with existing CommonJS modules, so currently you have to do this:

```
import Magneto from "js-magento-client";
const { MagentoAccountApi } = Magneto;
```

Which is not correct, but is in the process of being fixed apparently.

From the [NodeJS v10 docs](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_interop_with_existing_modules):

> When loaded via `import` these modules will provide a single `default`
>   export representing the value of `module.exports` at the time they
>   finished evaluating.
>
> ```
> import fs from 'fs';
> fs.readFile('./foo.txt', (err, body) => {
>     if (err) {
>         console.error(err);
>     } else {
>         console.log(body);
>     }
> });
> ```

All the comments above telling you that it's a bad idea to start out with an experimental feature are 100% on-point. The above is a good example. At some point this is going to change and you'll have to change your code. If you used Babel instead, you wouldn't have this issue.